# Wpautop in wp_editor not working

Tags: theme-development, metabox

I recently added a custom meta box with Tinymce support. I wanted to output the data as html. If I code p tags manually inside Tinymce it works. But if I switch to Visual mode, the p tags aren't automatically added.

I used the wpautop argument inside `wp_editor` but it didn't work. How may the paragraphs be automatically added?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) filter is only applied to `the_content` and `the_excerpt`. In this case you want to apply it to metadata. So you'll have to add the filter.

If you look at [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), you'll see that it is just a wrapper for [`get_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/). So it doesn't matter which one you use if you retrieve the content of the metabox. Unfortunately there is no filter call in there that you can use to modify what it returns.

So, that leaves you with the possibility to modify the metabox content after is has been retrieved. In stead of `echo get_post_meta ($post_ID, $metabox_name)` you would write `echo wpautop (get_post_meta ($post_ID, $metabox_name))`